# PHP Game Formula

Tags: php, math, formula

Basically I'm trying my hand at writing a simple football game in PHP. I'm struggling to think how a formula would work for teams to win games.

Lets take for example a team has 11 players each on the pitch and each player can have a maximum rank of 100 therefore a team would have a maximum of 1100xp to have a maxed out football team.

How could I do a PHP formula to determine which team would win or draw? I was thinking to do percentages for a team to win, but I was unsure how I would add a draw in to the formula.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: wat is ur game? people need to win if theiy have more XP?

Comment: It's a football game, well they aren't guaranteed to win, just more likely depending how much higher xp they have. I'm sure unsure of how I would write this

Comment: so ur trying to write a football game simulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't make sense as are you developing it as an app **"Basically I'm trying my hand at writing a simple football game in PHP"**. If you're trying to do maths with php, like the team with most exp will win, then its fine. If you know the basics of PHP:

```
$winner = ($team_1_exp > $team_2_exp ? team1:team2);
return $winner;
```

If Probability is required:

```
$t1 = "team 1 exp points";
$t2 = "team 2 exp points";

$total = $t1 + t2;

$t1 = $t1 / $total * 100; // % amount of chances of winning of team1.
$t2 = $t2 / $total * 100; // % amount of chances of winning of team2.


$winner = ($t1 > $t2 ? team1 : team2);
echo $winner."has more chances of winning this game"; // The probability which team can win!
```

Comment: But I don't want to guarantee, I just want to add the probability - is that possible?

Comment: its not possible according to experience points! find any other condition and tell me.

Comment: You can show the result as probability "which team has more skill","Luck is currently on $team's side" or anything!

Comment: Else, find an other condition and its just simple maths :)

Comment: Okay, I edit my answer. now check?